# Oauth 2.0 server with apache CXF

Tags: java, apache, web-services, oauth, cxf

I am currently trying to implement an OAuth 2.0 token server using apache CXF. My requirements are fairly simple. I will have 2 kinds of consumers, one would use the client credentials flow and the other would use a JWT token created by a client.

Using the [documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-oauth2.html), I have been able to get the client credentials flow up and working, but I am a little lost when it comes to the JWT.

From what I understand, the JWT token is a self contained token. In my case, it will be generated by one of my registered clients. I have created a JWT token using the following library:

https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt

Now CXF comes with a built in OAuthRequestFilter that does this part of verifying the access token, I am not sure what the flow should be when the token was created on my client server(JWT) as by default I don't think that filter will be able to handle it.

Now, what I am not able to understand is how do I handle this token on my server. How do I validate it? Extract the scopes ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have used `JWT`s, they can be fairly simply used:

```
private static String superdupersecret = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(24);
private static JWTSigner signer = new JWTSigner(superdupersecret);
private static JWTVerifier verifier = new JWTVerifier(superdupersecret);
```

So to generate a `JWT`:

```
    Map<String, Object> claims = Maps.newHashMap();
    claims.put("username", this.username);
    claims.put("role", this.role);

    //token is valid for 60 * 60 seconds = 1 hr.
    claims.put("exp", Integer.valueOf((int) (3600 + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L)));
    return signer.sign(claims);
```

And to verify it:

```
        try {
            Map<String, Object> claims = verifier.verify(tokenString);

            ...String.valueOf(claims.get("username"))...         
        }  
        catch (InvalidKeyException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | IllegalStateException | SignatureException | IOException | JWTVerifyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
           ...
        }
```

So you verify it in two steps:

- By using the `secret` to determine if it is a valid token and get the claims
- By checking the claims agains something, for example check the expiry date and if the user is a valid user.

Comment: HI RobAu, Thanks for your response. I am sorry I think I did not explain myself better. I understand the code for verification of a JWT, but I am unsure where to put it in my case. With the CXF implementation of oauth, there are filters which validate a token. As per the documentation here:

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-oauth2.html#JAX-RSOAuth2-ProtectingresourceswithOAuthfilters

So with that in mind, should I create a custom filter that handles both type of tokens?